How do you test a Pinia store state changed by a function within a component?
So I have a very simple test for testing a simple function. Basically I have a "uiStore" with a state "isNotificationsOpen". I have a component that has a function "openNotificationsDialog()" that sets this state. Works all fine, but when writing a test, it's a nightmare.
Here is my test:
it('sets the uiStore.isNotificationsOpen when openNotificationsDialog is called', async () => {
    const uiStore = useUiStore();
    const wrapper = mount(NavigationBar, {
      plugins: [createTestingPinia({ createSpy: vi.fn })],
    }) as VueWrapper<typeof NavigationBar>;
    expect(uiStore.isNotificationsOpen).toBe(false);
    await wrapper.vm.openNotificationsDialog();
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(uiStore.isNotificationsOpen).toBe(true);
  });

My problem here, is that the "isNotificationsOpen" is not being set to "true". When I log the action, it is being set, but is not reflected in the test.
Any ideas on on what I am doing wrong here?

uiStore is not a store created with createTestingPinia, this means that there are multiple Pinia instances. In order to avoid this, it should be done as described in the documentation:
const wrapper = mount(NavigationBar, {
  plugins: [createTestingPinia({ createSpy: vi.fn })],
}) as VueWrapper<typeof NavigationBar>;

const uiStore = useUiStore();
...


I've tried this solution before, but still have the same problem.

I'd expect it to work. Please, provide a way to reproduce

How can I provide away to reproduce this? Or which sharable platform can I use?

stackblitz or codesandbox may work, though I sometimes have problems with testing setups there. A git repo may work too
